# Volatile number of $stateParams

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a table to that displays data that you can search. It has multiple columns, but I don't know how many or what they will contain ahead of time.

The searches are stored in an object like so:

```
var search = {columnName:'searchInColumnName',...,otherColumn:'otherSearch'};
```

I have a simple state config which I utilize for holding filtering+searching. The filtering part works, i'm just trying to add the searching.

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $stateProvider.state('parentState', {
            url: '',
            abstract: true
        });

        $stateProvider.state('filter', {
            url: '/column/:column/desc/:sort/',
            parent: 'parentState',
            controller: 'Ctrl'
        });

    }
]);
```

I was thinking I could append `/search/?columnName=searchValue`, but the problem is, you have to define this ahead of time in the app configuration, and I don't know how many columns there are, or what their name is. Does anyone know how to do this, and/or have a better solution?

All opinions/comments are helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to use a known parameter, e.g. `search` and have the value of this be the serialization of the search parameters.

Your state configuration would look like this:

```
.state('filter?search', {
    /* same as above */
});
```

and you would use `$stateParams.search` to retrieve the serialized parameter.